# psexec powershell output

Tags: powershell, psexec, output

I try remote execute powershell script like this:

```
psexec -i \\host -u user -p pass PowerShell C:\tst\tst.ps1
```

Source code for tst.ps1:

```
$TempLogFilePath = "$(Get-Date -u "%Y-%m-%d")-LogFileEventLog.log"
Start-Transcript -Path "$TempLogFilePath" -Append
echo (Get-Date –f o)

Stop-Transcript
Exit 0
```

When a run command to remote execute this script, script locate on remote machine, in local machine in output nothing. Command running in cmd.exe. How i can get output to local console?

Comment: Does `C:\tst\tst.ps1` exist on the remote host? Is script execution allowed (`Get-ExecutionPolicy`)?

Comment: Yes, script exist "script locate on remote machine" execution allowed.PsExec v.1.98.

Comment: Have you tried `psexec ... powershell -NoLogo -File C:\tst\tst.ps1`?

Comment: How it help for me? It is off starting logo on powershell, but not help me get returned values on output

Comment: How about PSRemoting? New-PSSession and the like? You could record the transcript on remote system and copy it back to source computer.

Comment: why on earth do you use psexec when powershell already has the capability to run commands remotely?

Answer (score 1):

```
PsExec.exe \\host -u domain\user -p pass cmd /c "echo . | %SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe C:\WINDOWS\system32\Hello.ps1"
```

This construction help you to run remote powershell script, but script should be locate on remote computer.

and second construction

```
Param(
[alias("sp")]
[string]$script_path,
[alias("u")]
[string]$user_name,
[alias("p")]
[string]$password,
[alias("h")]
[string]$host_name
)
$pass = convertto-securestring $password -asplaintext -force
$mycred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $user_name,$pass
invoke-command -credential $mycred -computername $host_name -filepath $script_path
```

but i don't know how i can pass args string for execute remote script with param